# ActionEvent doesn't work in libreoffice using python

Tags: python, actionlistener, libreoffice

I am creating a for component command button by scripting in python. I fallowed the next tutorial https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-GB/text/sbasic/python/python_listener.html except that "com.sun.star.drawing.controlShape doesn't have the method addActionListener but AddEventListener

```
    oMRI.inspect(target )
def addingform():
    from com.sun.star.awt import Point
    from com.sun.star.awt import Size

    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()

    ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
    sm = ctx.getServiceManager()
    desktop = sm.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)
    doc = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
    doc.getCurrentController().setFormDesignMode(True)
    oSheet = doc.getSheets().getByName("Sheet1")
    oDrawPage = oSheet.getDrawPage()
    oForm = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.form.component.Form")
    oForm.Name = "Form2"
    oForms = oDrawPage.getForms()
    oForms.insertByIndex(0,oForm)
    oButton = doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.form.component.CommandButton")
    oButton.BackgroundColor = 15650253
    oButton.Name = "_MY_BUTTON"
    oButton.Label = "_MY_LABEL"
    #oButton.Enabled = True
    oForm.insertByName("_MY_BUTTON",oButton)
    oShape = doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.ControlShape")
    oShape.Control = oButton
    oDrawPage.add(oShape)
    oShape.Position  = Point(1000,2000)
    oShape.Size = Size(7560,4000)
    act = ActionListener()
    oShape.addEventListener(act)
    doc.getCurrentController().setFormDesignMode(False)


import uno, unohelper
from com.sun.star.awt import XActionListener
from com.sun.star.lang import EventObject
from com.sun.star.awt import ActionEvent
class ActionListener(unohelper.Base, XActionListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    def actionPerformed(self, ActionEvent):
        msgbox("click")
    def disposing(self, eventObject):
        pass
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~
```

I put an msgbox in __init__Self() and disposing and they  work
I want to click the command button and trigger msgbox

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, so that people can understand your question and be able to identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-programmatically-get-set-a-form-controls-events/45678/3, you need to add the listener to the form rather than to the control. So I came up with the following code.

```
from com.sun.star.script import ScriptEventDescriptor
oScript = ScriptEventDescriptor()
oScript.ListenerType = "com.sun.star.awt.XMouseListener"
oScript.EventMethod = "mousePressed"
oScript.AddListenerParam = ""
oScript.ScriptType = "Script"
oScript.ScriptCode = "vnd.sun.star.script:action_listener.py$test_message?language=Python&location=user"
oForm.registerScriptEvent(oForm.getCount(), oScript)
```

However, `test_message()` didn't get called. Probably there's some mistake, but I didn't want to spend too much time on it.

Note: Instead of form components, there are easier ways to create buttons, such as by inserting hyperlinks into a spreadsheet and then styling them to look like buttons.

Comment: acording to https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=71402&hilit=ScriptEventDescriptor&sid=c9d7250045716b0035c562422ecd6199 when you create one commandbutton you need to start in zero oForm.registerScriptEvent(0,oEvent)